# remotely pulling configuration information from BIND9 nameserver

Tags: bind9

How do I remotely pull configuration information from a running bind name server without logging in as root on the server where it is running?

I searched a lot and read many materials about BIND9 but still no answers.

I know there are some commands to conduct zone transfer or update zone resource data, but I didn't find any way to pull configuration info from a name server.

Comment: If bind is configured to accept dynamic DNS updates you can use the `dnsupdate` command line program to communicate zone changes to the DNS server, and bind will write new zone files.

Comment: Looks like a question for serverfault.stackexchange.com

Comment: @eckes Thanks for your answer. But I remember dnsupdate command is used to update zone files and unable to make changes or read configuration files. Maybe it's not what I am looking for.

Comment: @Paul Thank you. I will commit this question to stackexchange.com.

Comment: Yeah, I guess it depends on your definition of configuration. Indeed dnsupdate is only for zone updates, but thats the majority of day to day changes I would think. Bind besides that relies on file access (not necesarily root, but tyical).

Comment: @eckes Yeah. That's true. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

In short: you cannot. There is no provision in the DNS protocol to send server configuration. So whatever technology you use, it will NOT be DNS. And since Bind9 is designed to serve DNS requests and send DNS replies only, Bind9 cannot be coerced to send its configuration the way you'd expect.

You have to install and configure some other piece of software to be able to access the configuration. SSH is one of the most widespread such technology used for managing server configurations.

Answer (score 0):

You could use "rndc -s dns-server  dumpdb".

In named's configuration you point dump-file to a shared folder which is accessible from the system that ran rndc.